# Drop down menu borders

Tags: css, menu, border

I'm attempting to create a simple drop down menu for. What I have currently looks like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/Wt9UC/

Now, what I'm aiming to achieve is something more in the lines of what Fiverr has, see for reference.

[image]

To clarify, I'm attempting to get borders (top, left, right) around the menu item hovered and around the entire box of sub-items which appears on-hover. If I'm being unclear in my wording the following image might help.

[image]

I tried playing around with layers (e.g. bringing the sub-items to the front in hopes of the border line being covered) but it didn't work out very well.

My HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
#menu a {
    color: black;
}

#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 30px;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
}

#menu li a {
    padding: 9px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: #c5cbc9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}

/* Submenu */
#menu ul {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: -9999px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li:hover { /*had bg*/
    position: relative;
}

#menu li:hover ul { /*had bg*/
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 168px;
    text-indent: 15px; /*had bg*/
}

#menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi, were you able to make this work? is it responsive?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Complete tutorial for building a Mega Menu. Hope this helps.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu--net-15129

Demo Link : http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/819_megamenu/demo/index.html

Hover on "4 column"/ Thats your exact requirment/

Answer (score 0):

u need to do the following:

Add a "border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF" to your "#menu li a {}" and then move your dropdown 1px up.

```
link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cL2x7/
```